# Changing kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmmal on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

We have an Ubuntu server with 6GB of RAM.

We are trying to install Postgres but it is advising us to increase the values for kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmmal.

The server is solely a Postgres DB server, and we would like to change the 2 figures to

shmmax of 4GB, so 4294967296

shmall of 1048576

I've read up on how to make the changes, and have tried

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=4294967296
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmal=1048576
```

And then done cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax to check the results - this still shows the old number.

What am I doing wrong?

I will put them in /etc/sysctl.conf so they are preserved after a restart.

The error I'm getting is:

```
FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: No space left on device
DETAIL: Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=36, 03600). 
HINT: This error does not mean that you have run out of disk space. It occurs either if all available shared memory IDs have been taken, in which case you need to raise the SHMMNI parameter in your kernel, or because the system's overall limit for shared memory has been reached. 
Error: initdb failed Error: could not create default cluster.
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL 9.3 you don't need to. http://apt.postgresql.org/

Comment: Hi
During the install of 9.3 I got...


FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: No space left on device
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=36, 03600).
HINT:  This error does *not* mean that you have run out of disk space.  It occurs either if all available shared memory IDs have been taken, in which case you need to raise the SHMMNI parameter in your kernel, or because the system's overall limit for shared memory has been reached.
Error: initdb failed
Error: could not create default cluster.

The following google search led me on to the above....so this isn't necessary?

Comment: Maybe you have a really tiny shared memory segment by default or something else is using a bunch of it? Usually the configuration for Ubuntu is sufficient for PostgreSQL's needs now that 9.3 only allocates a tiny sysv shared memory segment. It's only trying to acquire 36 bytes! I'm not convinced that the real problem is insufficient shared memory.

Comment: How would I go about checking the shared memory size / and or what's using it?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/78044/7788 .

Comment: Have you read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html ? What's your `max_connections` set to?